How to read special characters 'ß' 'ä' from PostgreSQL database?
I have created a simple C# application that connects to a PostgreSQL database using Npgsql.
When I want to save the data of my SQL query it always fails because of names with special characters like 'ß', 'ä' ...
Error: Unable to translate Bytes [DF] at index 4 from specified code page to Unicode.
SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;
According to the database, the encoding would be “SQL ASCII”.
Code:
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                txtb_values.Clear();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        var value = reader.GetValue(i);

                        if (value is string strValue)
                        {
                                // Konvertiere die Zeichenkette nach UTF-8, falls notwendig
                                byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(strValue);
                                string utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);

                                txtb_values.AppendText(utf8String + "\t");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            
                            txtb_values.AppendText(value.ToString() + "\t");
                        }
                    }
                    txtb_values.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

I have already tried several encoding types, but unfortunately I always get the above error from the 10th data record (contains 'ß').
Already tried:
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(“iso-8859-1”).GetBytes(strValue);
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(“ASCII”).GetBytes(strValue);
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(“UTF8”).GetBytes(strValue);
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(“iso-8859-1”).GetBytes(strValue);
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strValue);
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strValue);
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strValue);


Once you get a C# string, it IS unicode. What does the string you get from the database look like, when you just look at in in a debugger?

Database encoding SQL_ASCII means that you have a problem. The database just stores the bytes as they are, and no attempt is made to convert the characters or verify that they are correctly encoded. So you'd have to figure out what the bytes are... Create a new database with encoding UTF8.

If your database isn't using utf8 you presumably need to tell Npgsql to deliver strings differently. utf8 is the default. Try to tell the correct encoding via the ConnectionString and hopefully then you get it correctly back as string without further encoding fiddling. If it does not help you need to get the bytes of the string from the server and then do the conversion yourself. Or if possible as already suggested change the database encoding to something useable.

Unfortunately, specifying the coding in the connection string did not provide a solution, it is also not possible to create a new one.
My solution, I encode the raw data directly into the format I need:
for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
{
     // Attempts to read the data as bytes
    byte[] buffer;
    long bytesRead = reader.GetBytes(i, 0, null, 0, 0);
    buffer = new byte[bytesRead];
    reader.GetBytes(i, 0, buffer, 0, (int)bytesRead);

     // For correct special characters
    string utf8String = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(buffer);

    txtb_values.AppendText(utf8String + "\t");
}
txtb_values.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

Works perfectly in my case, thanks!
